# How can I troubleshoot mqtt.fx broker connection issues to Live Objects

Tags: mqtt

I made a successful connection from `mqtt.fx` to Live Objects and some simple post to dev/info works, but if I try to post to dev/data I receive an error.
I'm just trying something simple from the manual
The error on publish is `broker connection lost : resetting client`.

The `mqtt.fx` lof shows that it successfully posted.

I'm just trying something simple from the manual:

```
2018-05-14 14:46:53,300  INFO --- BrokerConnectorController      : onConnect
2018-05-14 14:46:53,305  INFO --- ScriptsController              : Clear console.
2018-05-14 14:46:53,308  INFO --- MqttFX ClientModel             : MqttClient with ID urn:lo:nsid:mqtt:MQTT_FX_Client assigned.
2018-05-14 14:46:58,671  INFO --- PublishController              : publish
2018-05-14 14:46:58,674  INFO --- MqttFX ClientModel             : attempt to add PublishTopic
2018-05-14 14:46:58,675  INFO --- MqttFX ClientModel             : sucessfully published message {
    "s": "urn:lo:nsid:mqtt:MQTT_FX_Client!mqtt",
    "m" : "Model-1",
    "v" : {
        "counter": 32
     },
    "t" : ["Test"],
} to topic dev/data (QoS 0, Retained: false)
2018-05-14 14:46:58,814  INFO --- MqttFX ClientModel             : Broker connection lost: Resetting client.
2018-05-14 14:46:58,858  INFO --- ScriptsController              : Clear console.
2018-05-14 14:46:58,860  INFO --- ScriptsController              : Clear console.
```